# How to make a container (changing its width onTap) in a row move another container in that row underneath?

Tags: flutter

I created a widget Container which through the parameter onTap can change its width and then I used two such widget Containers in Row. As long as I don't press either of the containers everything is as I wanted(image1), however when one container increases its length it goes outside the layout(image2). Is it possible to create such a layout that will allow the second container to move below the first one when this one is extended(image3)?
My code:

```
// ...
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        const HeroInfo(),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 18,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [                       
            MyContainer(),
            MyContainer(),
          ],
        ),
// ...
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6naMu.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56G6p.png)
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpMmd.png)

I tried using ListView and Gridview (Perhaps not skillfully) but did not achieve the intended effect as in image 3

Comment: I think you want something like staggered grid view. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 1):

you can use Wrap instead of Row.

the code is:

```
Wrap(
      children: [                       
        MyContainer(),
        MyContainer(),
      ],
    ),
```